# Environment based appsettings in .net core application - docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-core, appsettings

I have created a .net core web application with 3 different app settings file

- appsettings.json
- appsettings.DEV.json
- appsettings.PROD.json

I have the following code in the startup.cs file

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
 {
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
          .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
          .AddEnvironmentVariables();
      configuration = builder.Build();
 }
```

During debugging on visual studio, appsettings.js is replaced based on the env variables`(eg: if env=dev -> i got configuration variables from appsettings.DEV.json and if env=prod -> i got configuration variables from appsettings.PROD.json )`

But after dockerizing my application, this is not working. I have used the following docker command to run my application.

```
docker run \
            --detach \
            --restart always \
            --name $name \
            --env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$env \
            --env containerName=$name \
            reponame
```

Anything is more needed for docker run?

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks good from my perspective, but please pay attention to the fact that Linux (if it's your host OS) is case sensitive. ASP.NET Core respects whatever the host OS conventions are in place.

Can you confirm that `--env ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$env` is actually `-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=PROD` or `-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=DEV`?

`-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Prod` won't work. `-e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=PROD` will work in your case.